# Cannot shoot more than one projectile

Tags: pygame, projectile

Shooting one bullet works but i can only shoot one and after that it stops working. I've tried to change my "bullet_fire" to False after KEYUP but this doesnt work either since then the bullet is only visible while i hold the arrow up key while the problem remain. How should i solve this problem?
Here is the code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

# Skärm
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1600, 900))

# Title och Logo
pygame.display.set_caption("Fjärt Spel")
icon = pygame.image.load('planet.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# backround
backround = pygame.image.load("0000.png")

# player
playerIMG = pygame.image.load("soldier.png")
playerX = 350
playerY = 836

playerX_Change = 0
playerY_Change = 30

# enemy
enemyIMG = pygame.image.load("terrorist2.png")
enemyX = 500
enemyY = 810

enemyX_Change = 0
enemyY_Change = 0

# bullet

bulletIMG = pygame.image.load("pung(32x32).png")
bulletX = playerX
bulletY = playerY

bulletX_Change = 50
bulletY_Change = 0
bullet_fire = False


offScreen = 1600, 900


def player(x, y):
    Screen.blit(playerIMG, (x, y))


def enemy(x, y):
    Screen.blit(enemyIMG, (x, y))



Running = True
while Running:

    Screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # backround
    Screen.blit(backround, (0, 0))

    if bullet_fire == True:
        Screen.blit(bulletIMG, (bulletX + 100, playerY))
        bulletX += bulletX_Change
    if bulletX > 1600:
        bullet_fire == False


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_Change = -10
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_Change = 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                playerY_Change = -70
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                bullet_fire = True



        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                playerX_Change = 0
                playerY_Change = 30




    # Ha player innan fill!!
    playerX += playerX_Change
    playerY += playerY_Change

    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 1436:
        playerX = 1436
    if playerY <= 0:
        playerY = 0
    elif playerY >= 836:
        playerY = 836




    player(playerX, playerY)
    enemy(enemyX, enemyY)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if bulletX > 1600:
    bullet_fire == False
#               ^^
```

This *appears* to want to set `bullet_fire` to `False` when it reaches a certain ordinate but, in reality, is *comparing* the two and throwing away the result. That means the first bullet you've fired is still going, has left the screen, and is probably halfway to Jupiter by now :-)

By way of example, this is similar to the following transcript:

```
>>> a = 7
>>> if a == 7:
...     a == 14
...     print(a)
...
False
7
```

You need to use `==` for comparison and `=` for assignment.

---

Keep in mind that's the *likely* cause of your issue. Since your question does not contain the code that decides whether a new bullet should be generated, it's a little hard to tell for sure. I'm therefore basing it on the assumption that one bullet at a time is all that's permitted (as in quite a few arcade games). Hence, if you never "destroy" the current bullet, you'll never be able to fire another one.

If that turns out to *not* be the case, you probably need to post more code so we can do an exhaustive analysis.

---

As an aside, I'm a little concerned about the physics involved in:

```
Screen.blit(bulletIMG, (bulletX + 100, playerY))
```

This appears to draw the bullet at the players current `Y` position meaning that, after the bullet is fired, it will track the player in some weird Einsteinian "spooky action at a distance" manner. While that makes the game a lot easier since you can direct the bullets after firing, I'm not convinced it will get a high score in the realism category :-)